# How to use a c++ concept to detect whether a class has a base or not?

Tags: c++, c++20, type-traits, c++-concepts, compile-time-type-checking

```
template<typename T>
concept has_base = ???; // What code should be put here?

struct A
{};

struct B : A
{};

int main()
{
    static_assert(has_base<A> == false);    
    static_assert(has_base<B> == true);
}
```

Is there a way to detect whether a class has a base or not?

Comment: There is `std::is_base_of`, but I doubt it is possible to detect if class has any base class.

Comment: What's the use case for this? There are a lot of classes out there that have a base class as an implementation detail, so there might be a better trait for your needs.

Comment: I want to use that to determine whether a struct is a pure c struct. @chris

Comment: So basically you want to check if the structure is a [plain old data (POD)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType) structure?

Comment: The POD concept is not enough, because a POD type may have base classes. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: But they can still be used a "pure C struct" and passed without changes to a C function. What are you supposed to do with this struct? Why can't it use inheritance? Is the file where you define the structure supposed to be used by (i.e. included) in a C project? Then why not use the C compiler as the verification of the structure definition?

Comment: When using inheritance, destructor should be virtual so `std::std::has_virtual_destructor` should do the job. When desctuctor is not virtual, inheritiance is another way to say composition so you don't really need to detect it. Wouldn't that be enough for you ?

Comment: reinterpret_cast pointers between base class objects and sub-class objects is dangerous. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` of pointers is *always* dangerous.I get a feeling you're trying to work around what is essentially a design problem.

Comment: I want to write a `my_cast<dst_p>(src_p)` function, only callable if `src_p` and `dst_p` are both not pointing to no-base types. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: The underlying problem becomes clearer. This is really the problem you should have asked about directly instead (including the pointer casting rationale), and then present the `has_base` concept as a possible solution you want help with implementing. There might be other possible solutions to the problem.

Comment: @xmllmx: "*reinterpret_cast pointers between base class objects and sub-class objects is dangerous*" It's no more dangerous than any other reinterpret_cast. "*only callable if src_p and dst_p are both not pointing to no-base types.*" I don't know what *exactly* you're trying to prevent here, as reinterpret_casting between unrelated non-base types is no less "dangerous" (ie: UB) than reinterpret_casting between unrelated base types.

Comment: N2965 can fulfill the needs